# Add multiple rows in existing dataframe based on a list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe df with 1 row and 20 columns:

```
id    name   age...... And so on
1      Ian    29......
```

I also have a list L

```
L = ['Doctor', 'Carpenter']
```

I want to create a column `'Occupation'` in my dataframe such that, all the other column values remain same.

Final output required:

```
id    name   age...... Occupation
1      Ian    29...... Doctor
1      Ian    29...... Carpenter
```

I was trying to iterate the list and then use pd.concat to append two slices.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can repeat index values by length of list and then assign to new column:

```
L = ['Doctor', 'Carpenter']

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(L))].assign(Occupation = L).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   id name age Occupation
0   1  Ian  29 Doctor
1   1  Ian  29 Carpenter
```

Another idea with first assign nested list and then [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.assign(Occupation = [L]).explode('Occupation').reset_index(drop=True)
```